# How to parse and get clean image source from Bing/Google news feed?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have created a program that will scrape Bing Newsfeed and analyze the content and email me the headline, a summary, and a link to the news. So far I have been able to get all of that correctly using BeautifulSoup.

I want to improve my program by also including an image of the news that gets displayed on the Bing Newsfeed page. I am having trouble getting the image source link because the source seems different.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.bing.com/news?q=Technology&cf=intr&FORM=NWRFSH').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

for image in soup.find_all("div", class_="image right"):
    print(image.img)
```

If I run the code above, it prints some weird things that don't make much sense to me. Here is an example:

```
<img class="rms_img" height="132" id="emb249968768" src="/th?id=ON.B139539B9DC398104440D89FAFB6F0C2&amp;pid=News&amp;w=234&amp;h=132&amp;c=14&amp;
rs=2&amp;qlt=90" width="234"/>
```

All the other img tags are also like this. As you can see the data-src here isn't ideal to get a link of the image that I can use when sending the email.

Can anyone take a look at the website (from my code) and inspect it a bit to see what I might be doing wrong or how I can get all the image links in a clean and usable way when sending the email? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src attribute of the img tag is perfectly ok and just what you will find in most website. It's a relative url (doesn't have the "scheme" nor "domain name" parts) with an absolute path (path starting with a forward slash)  , so it's the client (in this case your code) responsability to rebuild the full absolute url using the same scheme and domain name as the one used for the initial request and the path from the img tag - in your example, the end result should be something like "https://www.bing.com/th?id=ON.B139539B9DC398104440D89FAFB6F0C2&pid=News&w=234&h=132&c=14&rs=2&qlt=90" (which indeed points to the image).

NB: do not try to parse the url into components by yourself, just use the stdlib's `urllib.parse` module.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got my program running flawlessly :)